# Not all code paths return a value Error in tutorial

Tags: c#, return-value, mesh

> I'm new to C# and I'm following a tutorial that involves crating a mesh class. I followed it exactly and I have an error not all code paths return a value. I spent about an hour going over it again and again I just cant find what wrong. any help would be greatly appreciated. The AddToMesh has the error. The code is below.

```
"public static Mesh AddToMesh(Mesh mesh, Vector3 pos, float rot, Vector3 baseSize, Vector2 uv00, Vector2 uv11)
    {
        if (mesh == null)
        {
            mesh = CreateEmptyMesh();
        }
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[4 + mesh.vertices.Length];
        Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[4 + mesh.uv.Length];
        int[] triangles = new int[6 + mesh.triangles.Length];

        mesh.vertices.CopyTo(vertices, 0);
        mesh.uv.CopyTo(uvs, 0);
        mesh.triangles.CopyTo(triangles, 0);

        int index = vertices.Length / 4 - 1;
        //relocate vertices
        int vIndex = index * 4;
        int vIndex0 = vIndex;
        int vIndex1 = vIndex + 1;
        int vIndex2 = vIndex + 2;
        int vIndex3 = vIndex + 3;

        baseSize *= .5f;

        bool skewed = baseSize.x != baseSize.y;
        if (skewed)
        {
            vertices[vIndex0] = pos + GetQuaternionEuler(rot) * new Vector3(-baseSize.x, baseSize.y);
            vertices[vIndex1] = pos + GetQuaternionEuler(rot) * new Vector3(-baseSize.x, -baseSize.y);
            vertices[vIndex2] = pos + GetQuaternionEuler(rot) * new Vector3(baseSize.x, -baseSize.y);
            vertices[vIndex3] = pos + GetQuaternionEuler(rot) * baseSize;
        }
        else
        {
            vertices[vIndex0] = pos + GetQuaternionEuler(rot - 270) * baseSize;
            vertices[vIndex1] = pos + GetQuaternionEuler(rot - 180) * baseSize;
            vertices[vIndex2] = pos + GetQuaternionEuler(rot - 90) * baseSize;
            vertices[vIndex3] = pos + GetQuaternionEuler(rot - 0) * baseSize;
        }
        //relocate uvs
        uvs[vIndex0] = new Vector2(uv00.x, uv11.y);
        uvs[vIndex0] = new Vector2(uv00.x, uv00.y);
        uvs[vIndex0] = new Vector2(uv11.x, uv00.y);
        uvs[vIndex0] = new Vector2(uv11.x, uv11.y);
    }"
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: The declaration promises that the code will `return` a `Mesh` object - but there isnt a `return` anywhere in the method.  The name - `AddToMesh` doesnt seem to imply one will or ought be returned.

Comment: I don't see the keyword `return` anywhere in your method, where the signature says it returns a value.